# How can I use the variable in router-link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How can I use the variable in router-link ?

```
<Col
  span="8"
  v-for="(item,index) in this.data"
  >
    <router-link to='/home/workpanel/true/ + item.name'>
```

there it can not convert the item.name to the value, it is just the string:

```
'/home/workpanel/true/ + item.name'
```

how can I use the variable in the `router-link`'s `to` ? 
if I click the link, the browser shows:

```
http://localhost:8080/home/workpanel/true/%20+%20item.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `:` before `to` attribute. In this way you can use javascript syntax.

```
<router-link :to="'/home/workpanel/true/' + item.name">
```

Comment: can you tell me add the `:` what function it will have?

Comment: it's just a shorthand for `v-bind:to`. You have to use it every time you want to use a javascript expression (this includes vue data, methods, computed properties etc.) as the value of an attribute. Without it the value will be processed as plain text. https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html